# How to get data betwen <span ...</span> using preg match all?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

i am trying to get data between two `<span...</span>` that has specific color #ff0000 using the following code but i getting no data! could any one tell me what i am doing wrong ?

example of data:

```
<span style="color: #ff0000;">get this text1</span> |
<span style="color: #ff0000;">get this text2</span> |
<span style="color: #ff0000;">get this text3</span> |
<span style="color: #ff0000;">get this text4</span> |
```

php code:

```
if(preg_match_all("/<span style=\"color: #ff0000;\">(.*?)</span>/i", $code2, $epititle))
{
print_r($epititle[2]);
}
```

Comment: `'/<span(.*?)>(.*?)<\/span>/s'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I also recommend to use a DOM parser, here's a working version of your regexp:

```
if(preg_match_all("%<span style=\"color: #ff0000;\">(.*?)</span>%i", $code2, $epititle))
```

Only changes I made: I changed the delimiters from `/` to `%` because a slash is also used in `</span>`

The full output (`print_r($epititle);`) is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <span style="color: #ff0000;">get this text1</span>
            [1] => <span style="color: #ff0000;">get this text2</span>
            [2] => <span style="color: #ff0000;">get this text3</span>
            [3] => <span style="color: #ff0000;">get this text4</span>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => get this text1
            [1] => get this text2
            [2] => get this text3
            [3] => get this text4
        )

)
```

Comment: Many thanks all. Reeno your solution worked well :-)

Answer (score 3):

Don't parse HTML with regexes. If you do, a little kitten will `die()`;

Stable solution is to use DOM:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('span') as $span) {
    echo $span->nodeValue;
}
```

Notice that DOMDocument can gracefully parse HTML snippets as well, like this:

```
$doc->loadHTML('<span style="color: #ff0000;">get this text1</span>');
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, because there is no method named `getElementsByNodeName()` -- you probably want to use `getElementsByTagName` instead.

Comment: +1 for using DOMDocument

Comment: @AmalMurali and havana. Thank you both for fixing the naming issue! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$code2 = '<span style="color: #ff0000;">get this text1</span>';

preg_match_all("/<span style=\"color: #ff0000;\">(.*?)<\/span>/i", $code2, $epititle);

print_r($epititle);
```

Output

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (  [0] => get this text1 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => get this text1 ) 
)
```